# SoapUi 5.7.0 the response is always viewed in the raw window

Tags: xml, soap, soapui

after an update to 5.7.0, the response is always viewed in the raw window

[image]

what is the solution for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the jar and put it into your SoapUI 5.7.0 installation. Though the modification works fine for me, please note that **it's not an official distribution, and you are using it at your own risk.**

1. **Firstly you must close SoapUI and backup SoapUI-5.7.0\bin folder**
2. Go to your SoapUI directory (e.g., C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.7.0 on Windows)
3. Back up your existing bin\soapui-5.7.0.jar.
4. Download the modified soapui-5.7.0.jar 
   *You can download the file named soapui-5.7.0.jar in the link(click on filename) and press the Download raw file icon in the upper right corner.*

   from: https://github.com/karelhusa/soapui/tree/xmlContentType_fix/bin
5. Put it into your bin directory (replace existing bin\soapui-5.7.0.jar).
6. Start SoapUI and check it.

Source Links:

- https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/fix-xml-content-type-recognition-soapui-570-karel-husa/
- https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/issues/721#issuecomment-1114653409

Answer (score -4):

the solution is to wait for 5.7.1
https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source-Questions/After-update-to-Soap-7-5-0-is-the-raw-view-chown-by-default/m-p/228615#M32851

Comment: Almost 1 year later and your "solution" has not aged well... https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8PzL.png